# python code does not generate any output

Tags: python, neural-network

I tried to run the code in http://sourceforge.net/projects/triangleinequal/files/machine%20learning/NN.py/download

it run without any error.. but it does not generate any output. how can I get an output as a graph? please help

Comment: This question should contain the code itself, avoid linking to external sources like you did.

Comment: The code in question defines just functions which you never call. Maybe you can try to remove the "#" symbol which comments out the call of a function (last line in code)?

Comment: Thank you sir.. I tried removing the # already. but still no output. I posted the link because the code was too lengthy. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not meant to produce "output" as text. It prepares a plot but it never actually shows it.

Add this to the end of `test_regression`:

```
plt.show()
```

And execute with `test_regression` uncommented